# Regex to match 1 or 2 alphabets followed by 1 or 2 digits

Tags: regex

I need help forming a regular expression to check if the input string is ONLY of the pattern 1 or 2 alphabets (can be lower or uppercase) followed by 1 or 2 digits. Valid strings would be d1,d15,ha1,ha20 so on.

Comment: What did you try? This is a very basic question which you should be able to answer yourself if you know the slightest bit about regular expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
\A[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{1,2}\z
```

`[a-zA-Z]` is a character class that matches any letter, `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]` and matches any digit, and `{1,2}` means "repeat the previous element 1 or 2 times".

`\A` and `\z` are anchors, and they only match at the beginning and end of a string respectively (they don't match any characters, they just require the string to start or end at them to allow a match).

You will also commonly see the anchors `^` and `$`, I used `\A` and `\z` because `$` will match just before a newline at the end of the string and can have its behavior modified by options, whereas `\z` always means the very end of the string.

The following page gives a nice summary on regular expression syntax:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html